# tensoring coordinate ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, unique-factorization-domains

Let $B = \mathbb R[x,y]$ where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (called the coordinate ring of the unit circle).\

I want to prove that $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} B$ is a UFD. I know that we are tensoring up with scalars but how this will help me in proving that it is a UFD.

I know that: a unique factorization domain is an atomic integral domain in which factorization to irreducibles is unique (up to associates). And a commutative ring is atomic if each $r \in R$ is a finite product of irreducibles in R.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $A$? This is not true for arbitrary $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, e.g. $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is not even a domain!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I will edit my post sorry about that.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk but $B$ is not a UFD.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll have to think about why this tensor product should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the plan:

1. Show that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. One direction of this isomorphism is determined by $z\otimes p \mapsto zp$ when $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $p \in B$. Show that this extends to a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ and find an inverse!
2. Show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \cong \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$. To do this, we need to construct homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \to \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ which compose to give the identities. The only (good) way to build maps between these $\mathbb{C}$-algebras is to use their universal properties. A $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is uniquely determined by the images of $x$ and $y$ (let's call these $a$ and $b$, respectively), with the restriction that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. A $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is uniquely determined by the image of $t$, with the restriction that the image of $t$ must be a unit.
   Here are some hints: in order for the map $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ to be surjective, the image of $t$ must generate the codomain as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. In order for the map $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \to \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ to be surjective, the image must contain $t$ and $t^{-1}$. In particular, you need $t$ to correspond to a unit in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ -- think about the factorization of $x^2 + y^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ to find this unit!
3. Show that $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is a UFD, because it's a localization of a UFD.

Hope this helps! Happy to fill in more details if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I do not see how is this related to my problem.

Comment: Is not there any change of variables at the beginning?

Comment: Well, this is an outline of a proof that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a UFD. $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B$. Does that help?

Comment: How is this isomorphism? (I mean the one including the tensor product)

Comment: Why specifically Laurant polynomials?

Comment: Well, $B = \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ by definition of coordinate ring. It is a general fact that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_m) \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_m)$ (this is why tensoring with a superfield is also called "extension of scalars").

Comment: Can you provide me with a book containing this proof please?

Comment: I see the extension of scalars on pg. 360 of D&F third edition but it is not stated in this way.

Comment: You should write the proof yourself in this case! You can write down an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. I'll give you one direction: send a simple tensor $z \otimes p$ to $zp$.

Comment: I am unable to understand the details of $1$ you said .... if you provide me with details I would appreciate that.

Comment: Is there any change of variables at the beginning?

Comment: So why we are having 2 isomorphisms in 1?  ] Show that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: I added more details to the proof sketch. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know when I read it (maybe in 2 or 3 hours)